# PHP convert class object to array showing namespace

Tags: php

I wanted to convert an object of a class to array the code is bellow for this class

```
class ItemDetails extends ItemBase
{
    private $seller_id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($seller) {
     if ($seller) {
        $this->seller_id = $seller->seller_id;
        $this->name = $seller->name;
        
      }
    }

    public function getSellerId() {
       return $this->sellerid;
    }
}
```

when I getting the seller by call Seller and convert the object to array, by json_encode and json_decode, like below

```
$seller = new Seller($sellerData);
dd(json_decode(json_encode((array)$seller->getSeller()), true));
```

I am getting the output as below

```
array:13 [
     "\x00App\Repository\Seller\x00seller_id" => 1
  ]
```

The problem is I am getting the output with namespace of the class. Can you please let me know how can I omit the namespace?

Comment: Search and replace to omit the namespace?

Comment: Can you please give an example for this?

Comment: I want a solution without loop

Comment: @mdkamrul Why don't you want to use a loop?